# build c++ and OpenMp program in code blocks

Tags: compilation

the simple program written in CODE BLOCKS giving error while building. other linker option was `-fopenmp -lpthread`  giving the error " no such file or directory"

```
#include "iostream"
#include "omp.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(3)
    {
        int id = omp_get_thread_num();
        int data = id;
        int total = omp_get_num_threads();
        cout<<"Greetings from process %d out of %d with Data %d\n"; 
        cout<<id<<total<< data;
   }
   cout<<"parallel for ends.\n";
   return 0;
 }
```

need error free compilation

Comment: using GNU compiler

Comment: please give all the error message, does it concern "omp.h" ?

Comment: It is giving error  libgomp.spec  no such directory or file while building the code in c++ in code block .

Comment: it is not giving when the option of compilation was -fopenmp and probably giving problem in the option  -fopenmp -lpthread

Comment: I am not sure whether this is the problem of omp.h. the error which I got  " libgomp.spec  -no such file or directory " . I am using Code Blocks 17.12 and also installed TDM GCC 64 for OpenMp . The problem is there . Unable to build the program yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ubuntu OS, just do the following

Go to **Settings** -> **Compiler**, and then click on the **compiler settings** tab, then click on the **other compiler options** tab and type

> -fopenmp

To set the linkers, click on the **linker settings** tab, and type

> -lgomp -pthread

in the white space under **other linker options**.